# On the existence of $ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\log(f(x))}{\log(x)} $ under certain constraints.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, logarithms

I am considering a continuously differentiable real-valued function $ f: (0,1) \to (0,\infty) $ such that:

1. $ f $ is decreasing on $ (0,1) $.
2. $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = \infty $.
3. The map $ x \mapsto x^{2} f'(x) $ is decreasing on $ (0,1) $.
4. $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} x^{2} f'(x) = 0 $.

I am wondering if, under these constraints, the limit $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\log(f(x))}{\log(x)} $ exists.

Thanks a lot to anybody who has any thought/counterexample, or spent time reading this question!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, I realized I made a sign mistake when writing the question, I meant $x \mapsto -x^2 f(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: I asked the question on mathoverflow too and it has been solved: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252778/on-the-existence-of-lim-x-to-0-frac-logfx-logx-under-some